# Xamarin forms Location dont work correctly

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, location, android-gps

Ok I do not know if this is a bug, a framework problem or what. I am making an application that gives me the location of my cellphone. Everything works very well in the emulator, I'm using api 27 oreo 8.1. The variable status reflects and returns the granted value of the permissions. As seen in the photos of the emulator in the watch "yellow arrow".

Emulator api 27

[Image Emulator 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TuNJU.jpg)

[Image Emulator 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdAri.jpg)

But when I compile or use the xamarin player to run it to my cell samsung s8 oreo 8.0 api 26. The same code generates different results. Instead of returning the permissions, it returns an int of 0 and then in verification 4.

Samsung S8 api 26

[Image Samsung s8 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4s24C.jpg)

[Image Samsung s8 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4d6z.jpg)

Same different code result for just changing the device? Isn't the api 27 supposed to have backwards cmpatibility? What could be causing this? I am looking everywhere and I do not find something similar to this problem. Thank you in advance for your help!!!!!

the code

[Main Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCDIx.jpg)

[Main activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V29Xp.jpg)

[Main Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5zY4.jpg)

Comment: Please add code instead of images.

Comment: Posted the code